# Facebook Graph API does not work

Tags: javascript

I spent a while trying to make a basic code working to be able to use the `Facebook Graph API`. I think the issue is that the action is never launched when I click the button. I tried to add an alert in `document.getElementById('login').onclick = function() {` but it never goes through. Do you have any idea what could be the issue ?

Thanks !!

Here is the code ('000000000000000' is not my real app ID, I just replaced it for the post):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        var appID = '0000000000000000';
        FB.init({
              appId: appID, 
              status: true, 
              cookie: true, 
              xfbml: true
        });

        // This bit adds the login functionality to the login
        // button when api load is complete

        document.getElementById('login').onclick = function() {
  alert("test");
        FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                login(response, info);
            });    
            } else {
                //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                showLoader(false);
            }
        }, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
    }
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement("script"); 
        e.async = true;
        e.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js?xfbml=1";
        document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
<button id="login" >My login button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the correct code:

```
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I think this is to be used with Firefox, isn't it ? I was using chrome and it did not work either.
I tried to change the line as you requested but nothing happens...

Comment: it does not matter which browser. did you check out the browser console? it is hard to help with only "it does not work". debug your stuff, and read the information in the link i posted. as you can see, this works even in chrome 1.0.